# Problem with rendering templates with Fiber framework

Tags: go-fiber

I'm using Golang 1.21.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and Fiber 2.50. I'm having problems rendering other templates than `index`.

Here is the snippet that defines how templates will be rendered, the middleware list and the router:

```
    config := fiber.Config{
        Views: html.NewFileSystem(http.Dir("./templates"), ".html"),
        ViewsLayout: "main",
    }

    // Create a new Fiber server.
    server := fiber.New(config)

    // Add Fiber middlewares.
    server.Use(logger.New())
    server.Static("/static", "./static")

    // Router
    server.Get("/:page", pageViewHandler)
    server.Get("/", indexViewHandler)

    // return server.Listen(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port))
    return server.Listen(":5000")
```

The `templates` directory has the following structure

```
templates/
├── main.html
└── pages
    ├── about.html
    └── index.html
```

`index.html` and `about.html` simply show their names to see which file had been used.

Finally, he is how the handlers are defined:

```
// indexViewHandler handles a view for the index page.
func indexViewHandler(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    log.Printf("in indexViewHandler()")
    return c.Render("pages/index", nil)
}

// pageViewHandler handles a view for any other page.
func pageViewHandler(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    log.Printf("in pageViewHandler()")
    filename := c.Params("page")
    path := fmt.Sprintf("pages/%s", filename)
    log.Printf("path=%s\n", path)
    return c.Render(path, nil)
}
```

When I invoke `localhost:5000/` I get the index page with the following log:

```
2023/11/25 10:33:43 in indexViewHandler()
10:33:43 | 200 |      64.652µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET     | /
```

Now, when I invoke `http://localhost:5000/about/`, the **index** page is rendered again while the log is:

```
2023/11/25 10:34:29 in pageViewHandler()
2023/11/25 10:34:29 path=pages/about
10:34:29 | 200 |      60.623µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET     | /about/
```

which tends to show that the right handler had been called and that the right page had been rendered. But it's not the case...

If I invoke `http://localhost:5000/does-not-exist/` I get a 404.

In `indexViewHandler`, if I change the line `return c.Render("pages/index", nil)` by `return c.Render("pages/about", nil)` I still get the index page rendered!!! I believe there must be a default config somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

After a full day of additional research, I found the following in the documentation:

> All templates within the specified view directory are analyzed and compiled at the beginning to increase the performance when using them. Thus it should be noted that **no definition with the same name should exist**, otherwise they will **overwrite each other**. For templating the {{embed}} tag should be used.

*(...) otherwise they will overwrite each other.* We are living in 2023, right? How is this possible!

Anyway, the bodies of the pages were defines like this:

```
{{ define "content" }}
<p>The content of the page</p>
{{end}}
```

and the layout included them with

```
<head>
  <meta> ... </meta>
</head>
<body>
    {{ block "content" .}}{{ end }}
</body>
```

The variable `content` was systematically overwritten with the content of the `index` template and the same page was showing over and over again.

I removed the definition of the `content` in the templates and modified the layout like this:

```
...
<body>
    {{ embed }}
</body>
```

and all works fine.

Hope this will help some lonely soul...